# Reading Excel files without a library

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to figure out how excel files are written, so I can read and edit them in C# without a library (because I like to make work for myself like that). When opening them in notepad, all you can see is strange wingding characters, so immediately I thought, I might get some results when reading in a byte array. No luck, I do get a sensibly sized byte array, but converting it to a string ends up with a useless result!

So I guess my question is, how are excel files written, and how can I read them without a library?

Comment: "because I like to make work for myself like that" - I haven't heard that one before.

Comment: MS provides a file format specification (free download) - I would start with that IF I were you... being myself I would definitely go with a library (there are lots of free and commercial ones out there, most are well-tested etc.).

Comment: I have lots of hobby projects I like to be implemented in case you like to have (unpaid) work. But seriously, it's not a good idea to try it that way, because the format can be changed anytime, without further notice ... actually it is a propriety format probably and you are not even allowed to 'reverse engineer' it... as an alternative, why don't you output the Excel file as text and read that in your own application?

Comment: MS even provides a free library for newer Excel versions (XLSX)...

Comment: I see what you want... You should read this document carefully - http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/4/8/24862317-78F0-4C4B-B355-C7B2C1D997DB/%5BMS-XLS%5D.pdf

Comment: @DeeMac :-) I like to understand the inner workings of things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start would be this project : [Excel Data Reader CodePlex](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/)

It has working code, and you'll be able to learn the older format "xls".  "XLSX" is really more the new OpenXML document standard.  A link to an SDK from Microsoft for that:

[Open XML for Office Developers (Microsoft)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb265236.aspx)

I wanted to learn the formatting myself for some mono work I've been doing.. the older file format "XLS" isn't exactly something that you'd "learn".  Pretty complicated if you ask me.  Ended up just waiting for a mono product to appear rather than buying source from a number of vendors.. and porting to mono.